# How do I divide a number into an even number of groups?

Tags: logic

If I'm given a number, and a number for how many groups I need to split the number in, how do I split it into as close of even number of chunks?

`8 into 3 chunks -> 3, 3, 2`

`12 into 2 chunks -> 6, 6`

`9 into 2 chunks -> 4, 5`

`9 into 4 chunks -> 2, 2, 2, 3`

`11 into 5 chunks -> 2, 2, 2, 2, 3`

Comment: Divide the number by number of chunks. eg. 8 / 3 will give quotient of 2 and remainder of 2, so your chunks will be 3, 3, 2. In case of 11 / 5, you will get quotient of 2, and remainder of 1. Your chunks will be 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1. Now the chunk count is more than 5. If that happens, add the remainder to the last chunk and you will have your answer.

Comment: I understand how to do it on paper, but I'm looking for an implementation in code.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @GaryHoliday - Would LISP be good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, more or less:

```
int[] GetGroups(int number, int chunks) =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, chunks)
        .Select(x => number / chunks + (number % chunks > x ? 1 : 0))
        .ToArray();

var inputs = new[]
{
    new { n = 8, c = 3, },
    new { n = 12, c = 2, },
    new { n = 9, c = 2, },
    new { n = 9, c = 4, },
    new { n = 11, c = 5, },
};

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{input.n} into {input.c} chunks -> {String.Join(", ", GetGroups(input.n, input.c))}");
}
```

That gives me:

```
8 into 3 chunks -> 3, 3, 2
12 into 2 chunks -> 6, 6
9 into 2 chunks -> 5, 4
9 into 4 chunks -> 3, 2, 2, 2
11 into 5 chunks -> 3, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] input = new int[,] { { 8, 3 }, { 12, 2 }, { 9, 2 }, { 9, 4 }, { 11, 5 } };
int uBound0 = input.GetUpperBound(0);

int num = 0;
int split = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= uBound0; i++)
{
    num = input[i, 0];
    split = input[i, 1];
    int dev = num / split;
    int mod = num % split;
    string output = string.Empty;
    //int slice = num - mod;
    if (dev <= mod)
        dev++;
    for (int k = 1; k < split; k++)
    {
        output += dev + ",";
    }
    output += (num - (dev * (split - 1)));
    Console.WriteLine(num + " into " + split + " chunks -> " + output);
}

output: 
8 into 3 chunks -> 3,3,2
12 into 2 chunks -> 6,6
9 into 2 chunks -> 4,5
9 into 4 chunks -> 2,2,2,3
11 into 5 chunks -> 2,2,2,2,3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).